# Multiple Date Pickers on a Page - Working on Alternate Click (1, 3, 5...)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have many pages which contains multiple DatePickers, basically showing some Date Range (DateTo and DateFrom textboxes) and they are working fine once the DatePicker is opened for first time and a date is selected.

But when next time date is changed by clicking on a date again (this click can be after clicking elsewhere on page too), it doesn't work. Again for third time, datepicker starts working and so on.

Interestingly, Pages which have single DatePicker for a custom date filter, they are working absolutely fine.

I checked the code of JQuery UI 1.8.5  and found that the _selectDay function for DatePicker is also called alternately.

I am using JQuery 1.4.1 version with a minor change done to fix JQuery Bug 11390/7986

```
// jQuery.boxModel DEPRECATED in 1.3, use jQuery.support.boxModel instead
jQuery.boxModel = jQuery.support.boxModel = (document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat");
```

I removed this fix and found that the problem still persist, so it doesn't seem to be issue.

I am using the DatePicker as follows:

```
           <ul id="customActivityRange">        
                    <li class=" slvzr-first-child">
                        <label id="RangeFrom" ></label>
                        <input id="activityFrom" name="activityFrom" class="datepicker"      type="text" onkeydown="javascript:if(event.keyCode==13) setGLDates(2, true);" onchange="javascript:setGLDates(2, false);" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label id="RangeTo"></label>
                        <input id="activityTo" name="activityTo" class="datepicker" type="text" onkeydown="javascript:if(event.keyCode==13) setGLDates(2, true);" onchange="javascript:setGLDates(2, false);" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button id="FilterDateRange" type="button" onclick="javascript:setGLDates(2, true);"></button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Associate the DatePicker with each input textboxes as follows:

```
$('.datepicker').each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery Datepicker events instead of javascript events

please check this link for API help

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and found that the OnSelect OnClose are fired finely in case of 1st Click, with selected date coming correct, in 2nd Click only OnClose is firing with older date coming. On Third Click OnSelect and OnClose are fired finely with selected date. Checked on a bug for OnClose, don't know it's same or not http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5818

Comment: Could You please create a JsFiddle  snippet of your code so that we can have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Real issue was addition of dateFormat in option of DatePicker, somehow it was breaking the Select event and thus OnSelect was not fired, though OnClose was getting fired. Thanks for the help man.